# My bot stop sudendly communicate

Tags: facebook, azure, bots, botframework

I deploy my bot i azure , and i connect with Facebook channel. The bot start conversation immediately , but than suddenly without any changes the bot stopped to respond .

Do you have any idea what happen ?

P.S the web app is running normally ..i can access the web app . I try to restart the azure web app but without succes

Comment: is your webapp under the free hosting?

Comment: yes it is @It'satrap

Comment: yes. Under free hosting, this issue is known to occur. you can try going for any of the paid hosting. Even i faced the same issue

Comment: Facebook disables your webhook callback URL if it doesn’t respond in the expected way (status code 200) for any longer period of time. In such a case, you need to add the URL again.